# Adding primary constraint slows join performance on MS SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Main issue: adding primary key constraint to two tables leads to query times increasing from 1 min 30 to 40 minutes.

I have two tables with int identity keys:

```
Addresses 
(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    ...
)

Routes 
(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OriginAddressID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DestinationAddressID] [int] NOT NULL,
    ...
)
```

I have a view which joins addresses and routes on their IDs:

```
select * 
from Routes 
inner join Addresses Origin on Routes.OriginAddressID = Origin.ID
inner join Addresses Destination on Routes.DestinationAddressID = Destination.ID
```

When I query all rows from this joined view, the execution takes 1 minutes 30 seconds with the primary key constraint removed from both tables.

When I add primary key on column ID, the execution time jumps up to 40 minutes.

Both tables contain 400.000 rows. I tested this multiple times, the results are always the same. I'm at loss on how to proceed, as the 40 minutes query time is unacceptable. Primary keys should not slow query performance, as far as I know?

Comment: Every time you need help with a slow query, please provide its execution plan, so we can see what the engine really does. Preferibly using some service like https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Something else would appear to be going on.  Also, you don't specify on *which* table you added the primary key constraint.

Comment: If you create a primary key on `Addresses.ID`, the first thing I'd also do is create nonclustered indexes on the **foreign key** columns `Routes.OriginAddressID` and `Routes.DestinationAddressID` that are involved in those JOINs ....

Comment: "When I add primary key on column ID..." -- Which one? There are two columns `ID`.

Comment: Try executing the query with one or some specific columns instead of `*`, e.g. `SELECT Origin.ID FROM ...`. If the query runs faster this way, this might be an indication that using `*` is messing with the query plan.